# Stop autoplay after clicking on dots in slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

So, this is code I use for slider:

```
$('.autoplay').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    dots: true
});
```

And I want that after user clicks on any dot, it will disable autoplay. Then I tried this:

```
$('.autoplay').on('init', function() {
    $('.slick-dots').click(function() {
        $('.autoplay').slick('autoplay', false);
    });
});
```

But no help. Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ndjmx5dx/) from jsFiddle. Is this possible with `slick.js`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.autoplay').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    dots: true
});

$('.slick-dots').on('click', function() {
    $('.autoplay').slick('slickPause');
});
```

Comment: Hell yeah :) Thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

From one of the issues in the **[`github-forum`](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1005)**, I saw that you have to attach `init` event before initializing with `slick`.

```
$('.autoplay').on('init', function(slick) {
    $('.slick-dots').on('click',function() {
        $('.autoplay').slick('slickPause');
    });
}).slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
})
```

## [`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ndjmx5dx/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('.slick').slick('slickPause');
```

to pause. You can play it again with

```
$('.slick').slick('slickPlay');
```